# how to add item in list which is generated by query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my list and i want to add an extra record in it...............................................

```
var foremandata = (from f in db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs
                               join e in db.mqEmployeeMasters on f.tlEmployeeId equals e.empId
                               join c in db.mqCraftCodeMasters on f.tlCraftId equals c.craftCodeId
                               where f.tlJobId == jobid && f.tlCompanyId == compId && f.tlWeekEnding == weekend

                               select new
                               {
                                   EmpNum = e.empnum,
                                   EmployeeName = e.empName,
                                   DateWorked = f.tlDateWorked,
                                   CraftCode = c.craftCode,
                                   CCID = f.tlCraftId,
                                   STime = f.tlStraightTime,
                                   OTime = f.tlOT
                               }).OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeName).ToList();
```

Comment: Just make it a list calling `ToList` and add the item with `list.Add()`: `foremandata.Add(whatever)`.

Comment: Since you're already done `ToList()`, you can use `foremandata.Add()` for new data or `foremandata.AddRange()` for existing list with same type depending on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of projecting into anonymous type, I suggest you to build a strongly-typed DTO class which contains all required properties for query result projection. Below is an example of DTO class:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int EmpNum { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
    public string CraftCode { get; set; }
    public int CCID { get; set; }
    public DateTime STime { get; set; }
    public DateTime OTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use that class as projection target of your query:

```
var foremandata = (from f in db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs
                   join e in db.mqEmployeeMasters on f.tlEmployeeId equals e.empId
                   join c in db.mqCraftCodeMasters on f.tlCraftId equals c.craftCodeId
                   where f.tlJobId == jobid && f.tlCompanyId == compId && f.tlWeekEnding == weekend

                   select new EmployeeDTO
                   {
                        EmpNum = e.empnum,
                        EmployeeName = e.empName,
                        DateWorked = f.tlDateWorked,
                        CraftCode = c.craftCode,
                        CCID = f.tlCraftId,
                        STime = f.tlStraightTime,
                        OTime = f.tlOT
                   }).OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeName).ToList(); // returns List<EmployeeDTO>
```

And then you can add new item(s) with `Add()` or `AddRange()` method using that DTO class, depending on what you want to add (either single data or `List<EmployeeDTO>`):

```
foremandata.Add(new EmployeeDTO()
{
    EmpNum = 1, // some value
    EmpName = "[employee name]",

    // other properties here
});
```